# YouTube Data API quota 0

Tags: youtube-data-api

My quota for my project is 0. It's supposed to be 10,000 for projects that enable the API.
I haven't used this project with the data API in several years but would like to start using it again. I very lightly used it previously to fetch the last 5 videos from a content creator - that's all. So it can't have been disabled for abuse or similar.

I can't open a ticket in GCP for the YouTube Data API because it doesn't appear in the product list. The form to allow me to request an increase has a ton of fields and agreements that I honestly don't even know the answer to.

If I create a new project in the same org it's 10,000.

How do I fix my project with 0?